# Yii2-advanced template : logs frontend, backend and console

Tags: parsing, logging, frontend, backend, yii2-advanced-app

I am using Yii2 advanced template and i have a task to get logs from Yii2 backend, frontend and console, parse them (get rid of unwanted informations)and print them on my view. I know, that they are placed in **f,b,c\runtime\logs\app.log** but i dont realy know, how to perform such an action. What is the best possible way to do this, to be secure and well-created solution? Let`s say i have log like

```
2017-01-18 10:47:29 [::1][-][18g3r5tt6dspb7b3ib0bmfu4d4][info][application]
```

and i want to create something like :

```
[2017-01-18 10:47:29] [info][application][path\also][whatever\i\want]
```

Afterwards i want to sort them, probably by time or log type

```
[error][info]....[something]
```

,to print them on one of my view pages. I am not very experienced with the loging, so i am quite desperate what to do. Should i use **CRDU** view or new Extension or ...?
Thank you for answer and have a nice day!

Comment: Have you considered using `DbTarget` for logs instead of `FileTarget`?

Comment: I will check it! thank every help is appreciated ! :)